# LinkingIOS rctwebsocketmodule.connect was called with 4 arguments, but expects 2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm using Linking & LinkingIOS to handle app urls to log the user in. The app launches fine normally, but once a scheme url passes the user to the app, I get the subject error. This came up once I upgraded from 0.14 to 0.25, needing to upgrade in order to use some new 3rd party modules.

I've cleaned up the $TMPDIR for react folders, run `watchman watch-del-all`, re-installed node modules, and ran clean build in xcode. None of these fixed the issue. Any suggestions? Here's my code for handling Linking:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this._listenToLogin(); // this listens to another flux store change
  ProjectStore.addChangeListener(this._onProjectsChange);
  Linking.getInitialURL().then((url) => {
    if (url) {
      this._processURL({url: url});
    }

    Linking.addEventListener('url', this._processURL);
  });

  NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener('change', this._handleReachabilityChange);
  NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().done(
    (isConnected) => { this.setState({isConnected}); }
  );

  const token = LoginStore.getToken();
  if (!token) {
    LoginActions.checkLogin();
  }
}

_processURL(e) {
  const url = e.url.replace('deserttrail://', '').split('?');
  const params = url[1] ? qs.parse(url[1]) : null;

  const loginToken = params.token;
  if (loginToken) {
    LoginActions.requestApiToken(loginToken);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue. When I updated the project using react-native CLI, it stripped out the CFBundle values needed to setup the URI scheme. I added it back, and no more errors!

Comment: can u plz explain more on this, m getting same issue over android platfor

Comment: Not familiar with the setup of it on android, but for iOS, one needs to add the Info.plist file, so the phone knows to pass the urls to it, as documented here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html. I had added those previously, but when I ran the react-native update command, it removed them (replaced the file).